# Is FCM Token is Secure?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to know about getting fcm token from firebase is secure or not.
Because i did not found any official documentation for knowing about fcm token secure or not.

Comment: What is your definition of "secure"?

Comment: @DougStevenson Can anybody retrieve app specific fcm token without access of the app component?.

Comment: No they can't. It's totally unique for each app in your phone

Comment: @SamuelRobert it's unique but does anyone get app specific fcm token using third party?

Comment: No I don't think so...

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). We may be able to better help if you describe what you're trying to accomplish.