# Is it safe to expose fcm token or notification key?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

Is it safe to expose fcm token or notification key public?because i am consider to write fcm token to a public document with some data.cause in my case data would be easier to handle.I think this should be safe because without apikey the token or notification key is useless.but just in case I ask this question here want to make sure this approach is fully safe.

Comment: What specific problem are you worried about?  "Fully safe" is kind of a vague thing to ask.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55141053/is-fcm-token-is-secure

Comment: Oh sorry.I just want to ask if without apikey no one can do anything with fcm token right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking if someone can send messages to your app using only a device token but no API key, that is not possible.

Comment: If some trying to subscribe fcm token to topic or do other operation without api key is that possible?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, since the subscription is managed securely by Play services.